# How to open recordset from SQL Server in MATLAB via MS Access front-end

Tags: sql-server, matlab, ms-access

I've got code (below) to read data from a MS Access table into MATLAB, via an ActiveX server, that works very nicely. I'm now trying to use the same code to read data from an Access linked table connected to SQL Server, but am getting an error:

> Invoke Error, Dispatch Exception:
> Source: DAO.Database
> Description: You must use the dbSeeChanges option with OpenRecordset when accessing a SQL Server table that has an IDENTITY column.
> Help File: jeterr40.chm
> Help Context ID: 4c5966

So, the table in question has an IDENTITY column, and I need to specify the 'dbSeeChanges' option with OpenRecordset. My question is, how do I specify this option? I can see plenty of examples online of how to do it in VBA, but none that would be MATLAB-compatible. Here's my code:

```
% Setup environment
app = 'Access.Application';
DBAddress = 'O:\testData.accdb';

% Load an Activex server for Access
try
    svr = actxGetRunningServer(app);
catch err
    svr = actxserver(app);
end

% Load the required database file
accessDB = svr.DBEngine.OpenDatabase(DBAddress);

% Query the database for the required records
sql_query = 'SELECT * FROM dbo_PatientMeasurementResults;';
rs = accessDB.OpenRecordset(sql_query);
```

I've tried the obvious, but this does not work:

```
rs = accessDB.OpenRecordset(sql_query,'dbSeeChanges');
```

Comment: `dbSeeChanges` is a number (`Const dbSeeChanges = 512 (&H200)`). Have you tried `rs = accessDB.OpenRecordset(sql_querry, dbSeeChanges);` ? (or with the constant 512)

Comment: Thanks @Andre. `dbSeeChanges = 512` gave me an `Invoke Error (Description: Invalid argument.)` error, but interestingly '`dbSeeChanges = 4` fixed the problem. Haven't got to the bottom yet of why that worked, however!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Silly me, `dbSeeChanges` is a value for the `Options` parameter, which is the **third**, not the second parameter of `OpenRecordset`:

[Database.OpenRecordset Method (DAO)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff820966.aspx)

What happened now is: `Const dbOpenSnapshot = 4` - you opened a "Snapshot" recordset, which is read-only. So `dbSeeChanges` isn't needed.

If you want to only read from the recordset, than this is indeed the best option (but you should change your constant in your code to avoid future confusion).

To open an editable recordset, use

```
Const dbOpenDynaset = 2
Const dbSeeChanges = 512
rs = accessDB.OpenRecordset(sql_query, dbOpenDynaset, dbSeeChanges);
```